# Exchanging data between client and server without using sockets

Tags: java, webserver

I need to develop an application in which I have a Java script running on the client that needs to call Java procedures on the server (for example getting data from a database, I cannot do it directly from the client because the only port that is open on my Web Service is port 80). Since the only port open on the server is port 80 and a Web Service is listening on that port I cannot create a Java socket (am I correct?). What other options do I have?

Thanks a lot in advance, any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can not create another **listener** on the same server port - that is correct, but you can create a socket - that is the actual connection between the browser and server.
There may be a (large) number of sockets connections between client(s) and server but only one **listener** per public port.

Comment: That's what I guessed...Do you have any suggestion on how I could transfer data between server and client then?

Comment: Usually one would use AJAX https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ajax to create asynchronous connections form client side JavaScript to server side (pages/scripts/servlets...)  You will have to read about it yourself and then ask for help with specific problems if you have any.